# how to find contactid in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
RCustomerId   GiftRegistryId   ContactId   DateActive   DateExpire 
-----------   --------------   ---------   ----------   ----------
62            66               225         NULL         2010-10-11 
62            66               228         2010-10-13   NULL 
62            67               229         NULL         2010-10-20 
62            67               230         2010-10-21   NULL 
62            68               232         NULL         NULL
```

To check today date is >= dateexpire

if it is >= i want to check same giftregistryid  dateactive date wheather is >=  or not.

if geater then equal i no need to display contactid otherwise display contactid.
Eg :

```
      Consider today date id 2010-10-11

      result is    Contactid
                    228
                    229
```

Comment: This question is very hard to understand - please read it to yourself and fix it.

Comment: Where does 226 come from in the output? Do you mean 225? if so, how does it relate to GiftRegistryId 67?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT ContactId FROM TableName
WHERE GetDate() BETWEEN DateActive AND DateExpire
```

You'll definitely have to fudge things around by using ISNULL for null dates (I'd include it, but, based on your question, I can't tell how NULL values are handled).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
SELECT
    contactid 
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    dateactive >= '2010-10-11' OR dateactive IS NULL AND
    dateexpire <= '2010-10-11' OR dateexpire IS NULL
```

but it's really hard to understand, sorry.